# Is checking zip content on another PC enough to prevent data leak?

Tags: data-leakage, file-upload, zip, 7zip

Let's say I have two kind of files on my Windows desktop - first are files that can be published and shared with other people, second kind is confidential and should remain private.
To share files I compress them with Peazip. I am a bit paranoid of software bug that would cause other files to be added to archive (I realize it's probably very unlikely, but still).

Is checking archive content (by previewing or extracting it) on another PC enough to prevent possible leaks?

Cheers,

Dominic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is checking archive content (by previewing or extracting it) on another PC enough to prevent possible leaks?

Is it enough to be 100% sure - No, since the software used to extract might have bugs too. Or the original software might have added the data accidentally at some place in the ZIP file where they don't get extracted but are still visible when looking at the file through other means.

Does it reduce the risk - Yes.

Does it reduce the risk enough - Depends on what you consider enough.

Comment: I like the way you look at it, although seems like the more I think about that, the more anxious thoughts I get. Perhaps I shouldn't obsess over such things, and move the most confidential files to another partition with bitlocker turned on and locked.